# OpenGL Depth Testing not working (GLEW/SDL2)

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I am working on a simple opengl rendering engine as a project to learn C++ and OpenGL. I am following along with a [youtube tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5) that does it in java (which I know) and translating it to C++.

I'm hitting a snag trying to render a cube from an OBJ file that I read in with Assimp. It appears I haven't setup depth testing/culling correctly but can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. It appears that faces on the back of the object are not getting culled and are rendering over faces that are in front of them.

Images of cube rendering with some back faces being rendered over front faces:

[image]

[image]

I am using GLEW + SDL2 to initialize opengl and create a window.

I have made sure to set the following when initializing:

```
Window::Window(const int width, const int height, const std::string& title)
{
    m_isClosed = false;
    RenderUtil::initGraphics();

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum status = glewInit();
    if (status != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "WARNING WILL ROBINSON!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "GLEW failed to initialize" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "GLEW Error Code: " << status << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "GLEW Error Message: " << glewGetErrorString(status);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void RenderUtil::initGraphics() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
}
```

During the program loop I make sure to clear the buffers as well

```
void RenderUtil::clearScreen() {
    // TODO: stencil buffer
    glClearColor(RU_CLEAR_R, RU_CLEAR_G, RU_CLEAR_B, RU_CLEAR_A);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

I'm really at a loss as to what would be causing this. Full Code for the project can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/Laserath/OpenGLEngine) In case there is something missing from the question that I didn't know to add.

Thanks in Advance for the Help!

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: Please post **all the relevant code** in the question itself. In your case, you should at least add the code where the context/window is created and where the depth test is initialized. Could it be that you are enabling the depth test before the window has been created?

Comment: Updated the question to contain the relevant code and have a clearer problem statement.

YES! it was the position of the glEnable()s that was causing the issue. moving them after the glewInit() appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL state changes are only possible when a valid context is available. In your program, you are trying to enable the depth test before the context has been created.

Moving `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` after `SDL_GL_CreateContext` should solve the problem.